# Insert in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am currently trying to complete function that inserts a node in a binary search tree, this node includes a id, a movie title and the region of the movie.

I thought I had understood the concept, even though the program runs it does not give the correct output, I have tried different things, but nothing has given me the correct output. I have seen the questions that are asked here, and it confuses me since they use one parameter and i have a few more.

This is what I have so far

```
void BinarySearchTree::insert(string id, string title, string region, Node* currentNode = NULL) {
      if (currentNode == NULL) {
          currentNode = (*this).root; 
      }
   
      if (currentNode == NULL) {
          root = newNode(id, title, region);
          numberNodes++;
      } else if (title == currentNode->movieTitle && id == currentNode->titleID && region == currentNode->region) {
          cout << "Duplicate movie: " << title << " " << id << " " << region << endl;
            
      } else if (title < currentNode->movieTitle || (title == currentNode->movieTitle && id < currentNode->titleID) || (title == currentNode->movieTitle && id == currentNode->titleID && region < currentNode->region)) {
          if (currentNode->left == NULL) {
              currentNode->left = newNode(id, title, region);
              numberNodes++;
          } else {
              insert(id, title, region, currentNode->left);
          }
      } else {
          if (currentNode->right == NULL) {
              currentNode->right = newNode(id, title, region);
              numberNodes++;
          } else {
              insert(id, title, region, currentNode->right);
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: "...it does not give the correct output" is not a good problem description. Show us (a minimal) example of how you call this function. Explain what happens and explain what you expected to happen.

Comment: Could you also insert your other functions as well as how you declare your binary tree?

Comment: @-Support Ukraine, I have text files and the output come from there, it shows if the movie is found or not, if there is a left child or not or a right child or not

Comment: @Denisse show exact output of the BST before and after the insertion, and what output you are expecting. The current question is vague and hard to answer.

Comment: Yesterday was a good day to learn how to use a debugger. But don't worry, today is a good day too. Learn to use it today.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use standard algorithm, and containers ?
From what I understand from your code, movies are ordered by title, id, and region.
Define a proper Movie :

```
#include <string>
#include <set>

class Movie {
public :
  Movie () :  title_ (""), id_ (0), region_ ("afganistan") {}
  Movie (const Movie& k) : title_ (k.title_), id_ (k.id_), region_ (k.region_) {}
  bool operator < (const Movie& k) {
    if (title_ != k.title_) return title_ < k.title_;
    if (id_ != k.id_) return id_ < k.id_;
    return region_ < k.region_;
  }
private :
  std::string title_;
  int id_;
  std::string region_;   
};
```

and declare a set

```
int main (int argc, char* argv []) {
  std::set<Movie> the_movies;
  //insert, remove, find using set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually a solution to your immediate issue, which I suspect is caused by something that you don't show, but I find that you can code this kind of thing much cleaner as a function, which returns a node:

```
Node* BinarySearchTree::insert(string id, string title, string region, 
                               Node* currentNode) {
      if (currentNode == NULL) {
          numberNodes++;
          return newNode(id, title, region);
      } else if (title == currentNode->movieTitle 
             && id == currentNode->titleID 
             && region == currentNode->region) {
            cout << "Duplicate movie: " << title << " " << id 
               << " " << region << endl;
        } else if (title < currentNode->movieTitle 
          || (title == currentNode->movieTitle && id < currentNode->titleID) 
          || (title == currentNode->movieTitle 
              && id == currentNode->titleID && region < currentNode->region))
              currentNode->left = insert(id, title, region, currentNode->left);
          } else 
              currentNode->right = insert(id, title, region, currentNode->right); 
          }
      return currentNode;   
}
```

You would then call that with

```
  root = insert(id, title, region, root);
```